# MySQL Use prepare statement result in other query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use prepare statement result to fill my temporary table. Is it possible? (If it's matter I trying to do it within stored procedure.)

I suppose something like this:

```
SET @table_name = 'my_table';
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table_name);
PREPARE statement FROM @query;
INSERT INTO tmp_table FROM statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create temporary table first

```
SET @table_name = 'my_table';
SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS SELECT * FROM ', @table_name);
PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Comment: Many thanks! Such a simple solution! I think I should sleep more at night.